# CAN 2.0 - fault confinement - modification of error counters

Tags: can-bus

There's one thing in CAN 2.0B specification which I'm not sure if I understand correctly.

In chapter 8 - Fault Confinement - there are following rules regarding modification of error counters:

> Rule2: When a RECEIVER detects a 'dominant' bit as the first bit after sending an ERROR FLAG the RECEIVE ERROR COUNT will be increased by 8.

And

> Rule6: Any node tolerates up to 7 consecutive 'dominant' bits after sending an ACTIVE ERROR FLAG, PASSIVE ERROR FLAG or OVERLOAD flag. After detecting the 14th consecutive 'dominant' bit 9in case of ACTIVE ERROR FLAG or an OVERLOAD FLAG) or after detecting the 8th consecutive 'dominant' bit following a PASSIVE ERROR FLAG, and after each sequence of additional eight consecutive 'dominant' bits every TRANSMITTER increases its TRANSMIT ERROR COUNT by 8 and every RECEIVER increases its RECEIVE ERROR COUNT by 8.

So does rule2 mean that if node A sends an error frame and after sending 6 dominant bits (error flag) it detects that next bit is dominant it should increase its RECEIVE ERROR COUNTER? I thought it's OK that there might be more than 6 dominant bits in error flag (6 to 12 to be precise)... Also, rule6 says " Any node tolerates up to 7 consecutive 'dominant' bits after (...) "

Rule6 also says about sequence of 8 consecutive dominant bits. But for what exactly is this rule applying? Only for such sequences which comes after initial transmission of an error frame?

Let's have an example:
Node A sends an error frame, other nodes start to send their own error frames.
Node A sends 6 bits of its error flag, then detects 7th dominant bit (increase counter? - rule2)
Then we have another 6 dominant bits and after the 14th dominant bit node A increase its error counter again (first part of rule6).

Then we have another 8 dominant bits - node A increases its error counter again (second part of rule6).

Am I correct? I'm so confused with these rules and I need to understand them thoroughly. Hope somebedy will help me :)